# Count instances of value (say, '4') in several columns/ rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have survey responses in a SQL database. Scores are 1-5.

Current format of the data table is this:

```
Survey_id, Question_1, Question_2, Question_3
383838, 1,1,1
392384, 1,5,4
393894, 4,3,5
```

I'm running a new query where I need % 4's, % 5's ... question doesn't matter, just overall.

At first glance I'm thinking

```
sum(iif(Question_1 =5,1,0)) + sum(iif(Question_2=5,1,0)) .... as total5s
sum(iif(Question_1=4,1,0)) + sum(iif(Question_2=4,1,0)) .... as total4s
```

But I am unsure if this is the quickest or most elegant way to achieve this.

EDIT: Hmm on first test this query already appears not to work correctly

EDIT2: I think I need sum instead of count in my example, will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unpivot the data and calculate the % responses thereafter. Because there are a limited number of questions, you can use `union all` to unpivot the data.

```
select 100.0*count(case when question=4 then 1 end)/count(*) as pct_4s
from (select survey_id,question_1 as question from tablename 
      union all
      select survey_id,question_2 from tablename 
      union all
      select survey_id,question_3 from tablename 
      ) responses
```

Another way to do this could be

```
select 100.0*(count(case when question_1=4 then 1 end)
              +count(case when question_2=4 then 1 end)
              +count(case when question_3=4 then 1 end))
       /(3*count(*))
from tablename
```

With `unpivot` as @Dudu suggested,

```
with unpivoted as (select *
                   from tablename
                   unpivot (response for question in (question_1,question_2,question_3)) u
                   )
select 100.0*count(case when response=4 then 1 end)/count(*)
from unpivoted
```

Comment: For unpivot I would suggest `unpivot` / `cross apply`

Comment: Think you're on to something but I think sum() needs to be used instead of count potentially (count takes 0 as 1) and use of the unpivot function perhaps, hmm, thanks for the ideas though.

Comment: @user45867 - note that the count is over 1/null and not 1/0

Comment: @user45867 .. count assigns `null` to values other than 4 (in this example) and they wouldn't be counted. `sum(case when .. then 1 else 0 end)` would give you the same result.